# Problem With Sqlite Data Retrieving 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sqlite

I have an SQLite database, and when I am trying to get the data from the database, I get the last inserted element repeatedly. How can I get all the elements with no repetition.

The code I've written:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) gettingData {


    sqlDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    membersInfoArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];


     [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
     {

    const char *sql = "select * from ProductList";

     sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {


       NSString *prdbcode = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

     [sqlDict setObject:prdbcode forKey:@"Barcode"];


     [prdbcode release];


      NSString *prdname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)]; 


     [sqlDict setObject:prdname forKey:@"ProductName"];

      [prdname release];
       NSString *prdDesc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
      [sqlDict setObject:prdDesc forKey:@"ProductDescription"];
      [prdDesc release];
      NSString *prdstatus = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 3)];

     [sqlDict setObject:prdstatus forKey:@"ProductStatus"];
     [prdstatus release];
     [membersInfoArray addObject:sqlDict];
     [sqlDict release];

        }

     }

     sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);   

     }

     sqlite3_close(database);
     return membersInfoArray;
    }
```

I am retrieving the data as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *sqlArray = [sqlViewController gettingData];
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Prabah Nothing wrong in above method. How do you access the values ? Can you please post that code too ?

Comment: ok which code?? insertion of data na?

Comment: @Prabah You must be iterating returned array. That code.

Comment: NSMutableArray *sqlArray = [sqlViewController gettingData];

Comment: @Prabah try cleaning the build from the application and deleting your application from simulator and re run. There is nothing wrong with the code above you are writing. And should not be the case, still open database from the installed location and verify the records.

Comment: i do that but same thing is Happend..

Comment: @Prabah have you checked the database copied to the application ? Also try making small change in above function sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt; to static sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;. and at the end make it nil after execution. Check the database in installed location. I believe You will be finding something in that only. Path will be USR/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/SimulatorNo/Applications/yourapp/Documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Declare your array globally instead of declare locally in your method. Your problem will resolved.